# git: what does "o" mean in front of a branch name?

Tags: git, git-branch

when I type `git branch -avv` I get something like

```
git branch -avv
  some/branchname       9ff9335af Some nice description
o release/v3.0
  some/branchname       a12b3hg1f Some description
* release/v3.0          813f74adc Some detailed description
...
```

So `release/v3.0` occurs twice and one prefixed with `o`. I didn't find anything in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) - what does this mean?

**Update:**

My abbreviated listing above is misleading - should be something like

```
git branch -avv
  some/branchname       9ff9335af merged branch abc/def t
o release/v3.0
```

.. where you *could* easily guess what went wrong.. (line break)

Comment: Before everything else, make sure it is not the continuation of the previous line (wrapped because of the terminal width).

Comment: interesting. When I try it on my windows, I do not see the `o` symbol. I use `git version 2.14.1.windows.1`. Verified with both versions of the terminal. Which version are you using?

Comment: also, not sure why are you are seeing duplicate branches

Comment: D'oh.. @axiac you were right of course. I already regret having asked this question... Unfortunately you didn't post this as an answer - if you do so I'll accept it, otherwise mrks I'll accept mrks answer since he gave this hint, too

Comment: Well, it seems this is the Git way to tell you to either write shorter commit subjects or use a larger terminal window (better choose the second option). I voted to close this question as off-topic because it is *"a problem that can no longer be reproduced"*.

Comment: Setting the `core.pager` to `less -S` makes this a non-issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not git standard behavior. I tracked the `git branch` command nine years back and neither [then](https://github.com/git/git/blame/56b43607f975841e70203e55bba3c0b0228da6b0/builtin/branch.c#L403) nor [now](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/branch.c#L340) was there anything other than `' '` and `'*'`.

My guess is that this comes from either the previous line or from some other tool that you have installed on top of `git branch`.